# Nancyfx self host Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException:

Tags: c#, web, nancy, self-hosting

I am learning Nancyfx and I am trying to get my first self hosting project to work.
I am getting a http 500 response code and a "Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException"

My self hosting seems to be fine when I try this code in my HomeModule.

```
     Get["/ok"] = v => "OK";
```

This returns "OK" to my browser.

However:

```
      Get["/"] = v =>  View["index.html"];
```

returns

```
"Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException"......
```

I have tried various things including altering the properties of the index.html Copy To Output Directory which does in fact work!
But if you have very many javascript files in your content folder are you expected to do this for each file?

I have tried creating a folder called "static" and putting all my content in this folder and using this as suggested in another question

```
 public class ApplicationBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions nancyConventions)
    {
        base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);
        nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("Static", @"Static"));

    }
}
```

But this return the same error.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You're on to the right solutions. Yes you mark all assets and views ad copy to output (or as embedded resources, if you set up a corresponding view location convention), or you setup a custom view location convention to look directly in your source folder.

Comment: Is the "Static" folder copied to your output folder?

Comment: There is a static folder in the output folder bin\Debug\static\Content\views  there are no files in these folders. Is there a quick way to copy to output fro all these files?

Comment: I have just cleaned the project and checked the output folder and now there are no folders.

Comment: Guessing the folder should be marked copy to output

Comment: Alas there is no option for doing that. It looks like that you have to go through the entire contents of your javacsript css files and copy to output for all of them. However if you are using asp.net hosting you don't.